# Why called function pop up at top of the page

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, download, streamlit

I am trying to call a download button after text input is done. The problem is, download button always pop up at top of text input button.

my code:

```
import os
import streamlit as st

filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/lungsang/Desktop/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw"):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, file)
        filelist.append(filename)
with st.expander(" 1 docx-raw"):
    st.write(filelist)


def proc():
    for file in filename:
        if st.session.text_key == file:
            st.download_button('Download file', data=file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    st.text_input('Please insert the name of file to be download', on_change=proc, key='text_key')
```

In below  image : download button came up on text input button. I need it below :)
[image: screen shot of problem]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why to choose to take that approach, but you could have written like: By the way why did you initialize `text_input` without using it? Do you want to do something with the user input in `text_input`?

```py
def proc():
    with open("/home/Ubuntu/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw/A0.01-vocab.docx", "rb") as file:
    user_input = st.text_input('Please insert the name of file to be download', key='text_key')
    if user_input is not None:
        st.download_button('Download file', data=file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc()
```

Comment: above given code is not complete. Yes, I thought of using text_input to search for file names in directories and then download the selected file :)

Comment: What about `with open("/home/Ubuntu/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw/A0.01-vocab.docx", "rb") as file:` why did you use that? if you want to download the file

Comment: your code shows the download button even before I input a text in text_input. I was trying to show the download button only after input text is given and after clicking enter.

Comment: ```with open("/home/Ubuntu/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw/A0.01-vocab.docx", "rb") as file:``` this one is irrelevant, I just put there for download button. :)

Comment: Then you provide better understandable demo code because it looks confusing.

Comment: With the button appearing before the input is not a big problem to deal with. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I have updated the code, I was trying to: 1. enter the file name in text_input and 2. search that input file in ```filename```  then 3. after finding the file, pass it to the download button.  Previous given code is one part of it m trying to achieve :)

Comment: I have updated the code with my actual idea of how it should work. though its not working right now :)